Is there a broader interpretation for Ecc 6:7?
We read in Ecclesiastes 6:7 (CSB):

All of a person’s labor is for his stomach,
yet the appetite is never satisfied.

Compare that with Deut 8:3( KJV):

And he humbled thee, and suffered thee to hunger, and fed thee with manna, which thou knewest not, neither did thy fathers know; that he might make thee know that man doth not live by bread only, but by every word that proceedeth out of the mouth of the Lord doth man live.

In Matt 4:4 Jesus quotes from Deut 8:3 :

But he answered and said, It is written, Man shall not live by bread alone, but by every word that proceedeth out of the mouth of God.

DRA version of Ecc 6:7  uses the word ' soul' for ' appetite' . My question is : Is there a broader interpretation for Ecc 6:7 ?

The word translated "appetite" is actually nephesh = "soul".  "Appetite is an interpretive translation.

Thanks, Dottard. Does it mean that translators inadvertently restricted the intent of the Verse ?

The Hebrew word Nephesh (soul) is a very flexible term in the OT and translated in a huge variety of ways - consult and good concordance and lexicon.  In this case I would suggest a better way to translate the verse is "All of a man’s labor is for his mouth, yet the person is not satisfied."

I would say that there is a much deeper meaning than appetite. Soul is probably better for many reasons. Going back to the cursing of the serpent, he will live by his appetite (stomach) and seek flesh(dust) to devour all of his days. But in the case of fasting, aren't we depriving our appetite's for the sake of the soul? Isn't that what Jesus is doing in the wilderness when he quotes that verse? The whole point is to not satisfy the flesh, because our soul mourns the distance between us and our Creator. Like Jesus said, "Can the wedding guests fast while the bridegroom is with them?"

Although "appetite" is preferred by most translators (since food is implied in the first phrase), "soul" fits with the overall theme of the poem, including this particular section.

7 All human toil is for the mouth, yet the appetite is never
satisfied. 8 What profit have the wise compared to fools, or what
profit have the lowly in knowing how to conduct themselves in life? 9
“What the eyes see is better than what the desires wander after.”[d]
This also is vanity and a chase after wind. 10 Whatever is, was long
ago given its name, and human nature is known; mortals cannot contend
in judgment with One who is stronger. 11 For the more words, the
more vanity; what profit is there for anyone? 12 For who knows what is
good for mortals in life, the limited days of their vain life, spent
like a shadow? Because who can tell them what will come afterward
under the sun?

Whether it is the soul or the appetite that is not satisfied, the poet's repeated point is that "all is vanity, a chase after wind." If one eats, he will not be satisfied long, and if he seeks wisdom, his striving will be in vain. Many commentators question in what sense this book is inspired. But, like the Book of Job, it puts us in touch with the reality that, for many profound questions, there is no certain answer. For this writer, acceptance of futility constitutes a truer wisdom than a certainty that one's piety will be rewarded in this life. We may conclude that even though it may be the appetite that is not satisfied in the particular instance, it is the soul in the general sense.
